# SimpleDateFormat doesn't work properly on Android 2.3 and earlier

Tags: java, android, simpledateformat

I got a SimpleDateFormat like this.

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat=new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMMM", new Locale("tr"));
txtDateText.setText(dateFormat.format(selectedDate).toUpperCase(new Locale("tr")));
```

When I try it on `Android 3.0`, `3.1`, `3.2`, `4.0` and other latest versions I get this result.

```
02 KASIM
```

But when trying on `Android 2.2`, `2.3` and others.., get this result.

```
02 11
```

How can I resolve it?

Comment: Just FYI `KASIM` is `November`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same problem once. You may check if turkish locale exists.

BTW it is better to get month names from `strings.xml`. It will be easier to add multiple language support to your application in the future. Just get month number with default locale from the date object and its reference from your months array.

**Edit:** I wondered the reason for this difference between api levels and downloaded the source code for api level 10 and 14, then started debugging.

**Reason:** Shortly, difference comes from `java.text.DateFormatSymbols` class. Both apis have same code there but they are using different versions (or have different behaviours) of `libcore.icu.LocaleData`. Which is responsible to initialize `DateFormatSymbols` instace.

**Detail:** 
If `SimpleDateFormat` instance is created with a locale, this parameter is used to instantiate its property called `formatData` (which is an instance of `DateFormatSymbols`).

Its constructor:

From API Level 10 and 14 `java.text.DateFormatSymbols`

```
public DateFormatSymbols(Locale locale) {
    this.locale = locale;
    this.localPatternChars = SimpleDateFormat.PATTERN_CHARS;
    LocaleData localeData = LocaleData.get(locale);
    this.ampms = localeData.amPm;
    this.eras = localeData.eras;
    this.months = localeData.longMonthNames;
    this.shortMonths = localeData.shortMonthNames;
    this.weekdays = localeData.longWeekdayNames;
    this.shortWeekdays = localeData.shortWeekdayNames;

    // ICU/Android extensions.
    this.longStandAloneMonths = localeData.longStandAloneMonthNames;
    this.shortStandAloneMonths = localeData.shortStandAloneMonthNames;
    this.longStandAloneWeekdays = localeData.longStandAloneWeekdayNames;
    this.shortStandAloneWeekdays = localeData.shortStandAloneWeekdayNames;
}
```

I couldn't debug on `libcore.icu.LocaleData` but difference comes from that class. Values are loaded diffently from `LocalData` instance for api levels 10 and 14. [Change log can be investigated to find the differences on LocaleData](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/libcore/+log/66e8297c70daaf001ca199e4e4ad3ba5283396d2/luni/src/main/java/libcore/icu/LocaleData.java)

**Sum:**
If a `SimpleDateFormat` is created with an undefined locale(e.g. "xx") prior to Api Level 10, system uses numeric representation (for month names [1..12], day names[1..6]) of default locale's output.
After API Level 14, output is shown based on default locale if locale is not found.
(I haven't tested on api levels 11,12,13 yet.)

I suggest you to use system's default locale. If you have to use any locale, first check that if it is defined or not. If it is not defined write your own logic.

If you want to dislay a date, consider my 2. line on this answer.

Comment: This is better suited as a comment. Also, if the locale doesn't exist, it uses the system default. So it should still print `October` in uppercase.

Comment: No I've just debugged on a samsung 2.2 samsung gt_p1000 device with a locale "xx"(a locale which not exists). It returns numbers not names.

Comment: What I'm saying is it shouldn't.

Answer (score 1):

Could it be that the "tr" Locale is not available on those devices?

I think you can check it with:

```
for (Locale locale : Locale.getAvailableLocales()) {
    System.out.println(locale.toString());
}
```

Comment: That would still print the default locale value.

Answer (score 0):

It would appear that the older devices do not have the Turkish locale installed.

Comment: That would print the default AFAIK, November, in uppercase.